# Usage of find in solaris comparing to linux/mac

Tags: linux, macos, find, solaris, cp

I want to copy over only files ending with .php to another dir:

In Linux i have this command:

```
find projects/ -name '*.php' -exec cp -iv --parents -t copy/ {} +
```

In Mac this is also working:

```
find projects/ -name '*.php' -exec gcp -iv --parents -t copy/ {} +
```

In Solaris 10:

```
cp: illegal option -- v
cp: illegal option -- parents
cp: illegal option -- t
```

I read the man page, but could not find a solution.

Do you know how to solve it ?

Comment: The find command is fine - it's the "cp" command it execs that is different, and the "cp" man page you need to read.   It would probably work if you installed GNU cp from the GNU coreutils package on the Solaris 10 system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script doesn't use any Gnu specific feature so should work with any Unix / POSIX system:

```
find projects/ -name "*.php" -exec sh -c 'for i do
    mkdir -p `dirname copy/$i`
    (set -x; cp -i $i copy/$i)
done' - {} +
```

Comment: This does not work for me as this script always copies the next source file to the same destination target.

cp -i file1.php file1.php
cp -i file2.php file1.php
cp -i file3.php file1.php

Comment: Sorry, code fixed (I shouldn't have test with a single file ...).

Answer (score 0):

I found another one liner working for me on solaris:

```
find projects/ -name '*.php' -print | cpio -pdm copy/
```

Comment: This command will overwrite existing files without prompting. "-print" is not necessary.

Comment: You are right. Your script is the better solution than this oneliner.